# How to allow specific website/url using c# windows application program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows, group-policy

I have to make an application for parental control that can allow some website or URL to be access. All the rest of URL must be not access by the any user until unless the program has been stopped.

I have tried to do with the group policy and I can do with group policy. I want to fixed this issue programmatically. At least if this could be done by command line that would be better for me to implement.

Comment: [Group Policy API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374177.aspx).